# What happens when I terminate a process and the socket send buffer is not empty?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, tcp

In Windows (and probably in other operating systems), if a process has a TCP connection with another process on another machine, and then I terminate the process, an RST packet will be sent to the other machine to indicate the end of the connection.

Now imagine that when the process is terminated, there were still some data left in the send buffer. What will happen in this case, will these remaining data be sent to the other machine followed by an RST packet, or will these remaining data be ignored and only an RST packet is sent?